# Wrong derivation of limit of Cesàro mean

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

It's known that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=a\Rightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{n}=a$$

Consider the following derivation:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_{i}}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_{i}}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}0=0$$

Question 1. As far as I understand, the mistake is in exchanging the limit and the summation. Right?

Question 2. Recall that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(y_{n}+z_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_{n}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_{n}$, if the last 2 limits are finite. The mistake in the above solution gave me a hint that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(y_{n}+z_{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y_{n}+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_{n}$ can be extended only to finite sums. Right?

Comment: To address question 1: the sum runs from 1 to $n$ so you can't move the limit inside the sum because that $n$ needs to be affected by the limit operation as well.  That's why you don't get a sensible answer.
For question 2, are you asking if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^i_n$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^i_n$?

Comment: No. Why did you add powers? I'm asking how far we can extend the rule that helps us to find limit of sum by summing the limits of summands? My wrong solution of limit of Cesaro mean shows that such an exchange fails when applied to sum of countable summands.

Comment: They're not powers, they're indices.  I was asking if you wanted to interchange summation and limit for an infinite sum of sequences each with an infinite number of terms.  So the sequences are indexed by $i$ and the terms of each sequence are indexed by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: you can not exchange limit and sum in this case because sum is bound by $n$ that is the index of limit.

Question 2: in this case, sum is on index other than $n$. Or

$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{m}y_n^{(k)}=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{m}\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}y_n^{(k)}$

Sum must be finite in order to exchange order of $n$ and $k$.